# Solving limits using $\ln e$

Tags: limits

I cant fully grasp how these two steps are performed. Isn't $\ln e$ only true if the value behind the $\ln$ equals the value of the polynomial?

$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \ln a {1\over {1\over t}* \ln(t+1)} = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \ln a {1\over \ln(t+1)^{1\over t}} = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \ln a {1\over \ln e}$$

However here they seem to assume that $\ln(t+1)^{1\over t}$ equals $\ln e$? I am probably just wrong on this, could anyone explain?..

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: $\ln e=1$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}(1+t)^{1/t}=e.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrong shortcut was taken, as in $$ \lim\limits_{t \to 0}  {\ln a\over \ln e}$$ there is no $t$ in the argument of the limit.

A more correct derivation is

$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} {\ln a \over \ln(t+1)^{1\over t}}= {\ln a \over \lim\limits_{t \to 0}\ln(t+1)^{1\over t}}= {\ln a \over \ln\left(\lim\limits_{t \to 0}(t+1)^{1\over t}\right)}={\ln a\over\ln e}.$$

The substitutions are justified by the fact that the inverse and the logarithm functions are continuous, so that they commute with the limit.

Comment: And you know that you can move the limit to the denominator because there is no $t$ in the numerator or?..

Comment: The substitutions are justified by the fact that the inverse and the logarithm functions are continuous, so that they commute with the limit.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you possibly try to word this differently? I'm not a native English speaker and I don't fully understand what you mean..

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 What don't you understand ?

Comment: What does commuting with the limit mean?..

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 That you can exchange them freely. Limit of the function or function of the limit, like $\lim x^2=(\lim x)^2$.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They use that $e=\lim_{t\to0}(1+t)^{1/t}$.
Try it on your calculator: $1.1^{10},1.01^{100},1.001^{1000}$ approaches a limit.

Comment: But itsn't it supposed to be $\lim \limits_{t \to 0} (1+t)^{1 + t}$ in order for it to $= e$?

Comment: No.  A more familiar version might be $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n$

Comment: Ooh okay, and that equals $e$ as well? If so I got it!